# Paperclip: :hash as filename not updated when refreshing thumbnails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using Rails 3.2.1 and using the following setting for paperclip

```
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:hash.:extension",
:url => "/system/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:hash.:extension",
:hash_secret => "somesecret"
```

I started with `:styles => { :thumb => '200x200>' }`, and later added a new style `:styles => { :thumb => '200x200>', :mini => '100x100#' }`.
When I run the rake task:

```
rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles RAILS_ENV=production
```

The new styles are not displayed correctly on the webpage. I checked the log file which says the thumbnails are successfully generated and stored. But the URL it used are not the same as the ones used by the webpage. Only the :hash part is different. Looks like each time I refresh the thumbnials, paperclip will generate a new hash but the `attachment.url(:style)` always return the same hash.

I also tried `rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails CLASS=ClassName` but it's the same effect. New files were generated in the directory but the URL used by the webpage did not change which means that the browser still cannot find the proper files.

UPDATE: Problem solved in paperclip 3.0. See this issue on Github: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/802

Comment: @timpone Problem fixed by Paperclip author https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/802